# How does the lymphatic system filter blood?

Tags: lymphatic-system

One of the main functions of the lymphatic system is to filter blood. How exactly is it done? 
Its quite hard to find an exact answer.

Comment: Can you provide a reference? I've never heard of it being described as a blood filter before as it doesn't carry blood.

Comment: @OliverHouston My biology teacher told me 'how does the lymphatic system filter blood?' is there any filtering that takes place in the lymphatic system?

Comment: OK, I'd forgotten about the spleen being part of the lymph system... See the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

The [spleen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spleen) is an integral part of the lymphatic system, and it is a major filter of blood.

The way this is done is by removing old, distorted, or antibody-coated red blood cells from circulation.

Interestingly, the spleen is enlarged with many leukemias and lymphomas.

Comment: Need more detail, just enough to know I'm on track.